# C++ SFINAE partial specialization

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, template-specialization

I've been trying to define an auxiliary class to help me work with template methods in which I would like a generic implementation both for complex and real types.

That has been my attempt so far:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<complex>


template<class T>
struct is_complex{ static constexpr bool value = false;};

template<class T>
struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : 
    std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_integral<T>::value ||
    std::is_floating_point<T>::value>{};

template<class T>
struct is_arithmetic:
    std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_integral<T>::value ||
    std::is_floating_point<T>::value ||
    is_complex<T>::value>{};


template<class T,
typename std::enable_if_t<is_arithmetic<T>::value,int> =0>
struct real_type {typedef T type;};

template<class T>
struct real_type<typename std::complex<T>>{typedef T type;};
```

I want to get something like

```
typename real_type<std::complex<double>> myVar1;//myVar1 is double
typename real_type<double> myVar2;//myVar2 is double
```

I was able to make it work as long as I didn't care that non-arithmetic types also had `real_type<T>::type`. But now that I have added this additional constraint, I cannot make it work and I don't really see why.

To clarify: I would like that calls like `real_type<std::string>::type` would generate compile-time errors. I want these calls to be valid only to arithmetic (including complex) and integral types.

The compiler error of my latest attempt was:

```
non-type template argument specializes a template parameter with dependent type 'typename std::enable_if_t<is_arithmetic<T>::value, int>' (aka 'typename enable_if<is_arithmetic<T>::value, int>::type')
```

But I don't know how to deal with it. If this information is useful, I have access to compilers supporting C++17.

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the compiler error you describe?

Comment: It's the code that I've put in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is done with specialization and a template defaulted parameter.

I mean

```
template <typename, typename = void>
struct real_type;

template <typename T>
struct real_type<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct real_type<std::complex<T>, void>
 { using type = T; };
```

where you have a separate specialization for `std::complex` and, as observed by Patrick Roberts (thanks), without `std::complex` your `is_arithmetic` become a duplicate of `std::is_arithmetic` (so is better directly use `std::is_arithmetic`).

You get

```
real_type<int>                 r1;   // compile
real_type<std::complex<float>> r2;   // compile
//real_type<std::string>         r3; // compilation error
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts  - Good point. Answer simplified. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. This fits me perfectly and it looks extremely clean. I just needed to add `std::is_integral_v<T>` and I can use it directly in the code.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a slightly more concise implementation that works more generally (which requires c++17):

```
#include <type_traits>

// catch all for single parameters that have 0 template parameters 
template <typename T>
struct real_type{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>);
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T>
using real_type_t = typename real_type<T>::type;

// magically catch anything which matches V<T, Ts...> and exposes T as `type`
template <template <typename...> typename V, typename T, typename...Ts>
struct real_type<V<T, Ts...>>{
    using type = real_type_t<T>;
};

#include <vector>
#include <complex>

using d = real_type_t<double>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<d, double>);
using d2 = real_type_t<std::vector<double>>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<d2, double>);
using d3 = real_type_t<std::complex<double>>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<d3, double>);

// doesn't compile
struct NotValid {};
using d4 = real_type_t<std::vector<NotValid>>;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer @mattlangford! I have tried to explain it better in my question, but what I meant is that I would like calls such as `real_type<std::string>::type` to result in a compile-time error. But your idea of getting `T` from `V<T>` could be quite useful, even if I had to specialize it individually for each class `V` I am interested in.

Comment: I updated it slightly so that it should do what you're thinking! (funny enough you'd still need an override for `std::string`, since `std::string` is basically a `std::vector<char>` and `char` is arithmetic)

Comment: `std::string` is a `std::basic_string<char>`. I don't think a template template parameter is necessary here as `std::complex` is the only relevant template class to specialize on.